# Printing PDF from browser via javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

Currently I have a PDF embeded in an html object which I'm printing via including the following javascript inside the pdf:

```
'this.print({bUI: true, bSilent: true, bShrinkToFit: true});'
```

however, sometimes the acrobat reader plugin in firefox, reads the javascript, tries to print an empty document and fails, then afterwards it loads the pdf and correctly prints it.

Is there a way in which i can force the pdf to completely load before automatically printing it?

Comment: have you tried using  event handlers, notably the onReady javascript function? That should wait until all the other javascript is completed executing, thus the document should be loaded. I'm not sure how it deals with flash however....

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Flexpaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com), an open source web doc viewer.